# как по id получить svg и записать его в room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, room

Есть data class

```
@Entity(tableName = CreatedExerciseEntity.CREATED_EXEC_TABLE)
data class CreatedExerciseEntity(

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
val id : Int,
var createTimestamp : String,
var exerciseName : String,
var exerciseIcon : Int,
var colorExerciseBg : Int,
var numberOfTouch : Int = 0,
var repsPerSetInDay : Int = 0

) : Serializable{
companion object{
    const val CREATED_EXEC_TABLE = "createdExerciseTable"
 }
}
```

Есть поле **exerciseIcon** которое принимает int, оно хранит в себе id svg файла.
Что нужно сделать, что-бы получить bitmap svg по id, или как то сохранить в бд, что бы к элементу было обращение не по его id , а именно сохранение самого элемента в бд.

Comment: Не вполне ясно что вам нужно. Писать в БД файл - не лучшая идея, очень редко можно обосновать необходимость этого. Хранить ID файла же - почти всегда - отличная идея. В связи с этим ваш вопрос, наверное, скорее про получение картинки из ресурсов по его ID. Правда, вроде, ID при ребилде приложения, если файлы в ресурсах, могут поменяться. В таком случае лучше хранить имена вместо ID. Но тут надо будет учитывать то, что имена файлов могут быть изменены - тогда надо будет миграции накатывать на БД. По имени же или по ID вытащить картинку для её отображения - просто. Если вам не это нужно-напишите

Comment: Уточните что за id такой? Это id ресурса из res/drawable, например? Если да, то не делайте так. id может поменяться после следующей компиляции.

Comment: Вот в этом была и проблема. "Картинки" были в ресурсах проекта, и при ребилде отображение картинок было некорректно, так как вызывал их по id из бд. Выходит, лучший вариантом в моё случае - сохранить в бд имя файла, чем id?

Comment: Каким способом можно получить название файла из ресурсов с помощью кода?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getResourceEntryName(int)